# ASP.Net CType unable to convert "£1,234.56" to Decimal - Need detailed list of influences

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is a common question - and it has several common answers.
My problem is that none of them have worked.

The code is entirely typical, a CType to a Decimal, which fails due to globalization settings.

```
Console.write( CType("£1,234.56", Decimal) )
>>> Conversion from string "£1,234.56" to type 'Decimal' is not valid.
```

My issue is this particular computer isn't converting the value after several different attempts to fix it.

So far, in no particular order of desperation:

1. Region settings. Made sure they were (United Kingdom) [en-GB], restarted.
2. IIS, ".NET Globalisation", Culture is set to Invariant Language (Invariant Country).
3. IIS, ".NET Globalisation", Culture is set to (United Kingdom) [en-GB].
4. Region settings, Administrative tab, Copy locale settings.

I've yet to try:

5. Set in web.config ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Have you tried Decimal.Parse which allows different parameters to be set?

Answer (score 1):

As the_lotus mentioned, [Decimal.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s84kdbzx(v=vs.110).aspx) will work:

```
Option Infer On
Imports System.Globalization

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim s = "£1,234.56"
        Dim d = Decimal.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Currency, New CultureInfo("en-GB"))
        Console.WriteLine(d) ' outputs 1234.56

        s = "$1,234.56"
        d = Decimal.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Currency, New CultureInfo("en-US"))
        Console.WriteLine(d) ' outputs 1234.56

        If Decimal.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Currency, New CultureInfo("en-GB"), d) Then
            Console.WriteLine(d)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Could not parse.")
        End If

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

An inferior way would be to remove everything which doesn't belong in a number:

```
Dim s = "£1,234.56"
Dim re As New Regex("[^0-9,.]")
Dim t = re.Replace(s, "")
Console.WriteLine(CType(t, Decimal)) ' outputs 1234.56
```

It isn't as good because you don't get to check if the currency symbol was the one you expected.

Comment: Thanks for those tips. I'm looking for something in the environment before changing the code. So if you've got anything on that side I've missed give me a shout. Though if we can't figure this one out, I'll make the code change you suggest. =)